How do you escape countablity in Hott?
In homotopy type theory the type $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbf{2}$ is inhabited by countable witnesses as each witness is defined by a lambda.  If I wish to reason about uncountable things how do I do it within HoTT?

The type $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbf{2}$ is not countable in HoTT. The usual diagonal argument (e.g. via Lawvere's fixed point theorem) goes through just fine.
There is a countable infinity of syntactic terms inhabiting that type, but that's true of any theory, including ZFC, and is not specific to HoTT. That does not say anything about what the theory can prove.

So I am misunderstanding the comment on page 48 of the HoTT book about $A\to\mathbf{2}$ being the decidable subsets of A?

Probably? That statement isn't saying much beyond the definition of "decidable" in type theory.
